# How to copy cell content from one remote database to another?

Tags: mysql

I have multiple remote databases at two different web hosters. I want to copy some cell values within a table from one remote database to another remote database from my local pc. How can i automate this?

Comment: You could create a php script to do this, im not sure if its possible with just MYSQL alone.

Comment: There seem to be 2 questions here are you having a problem with copying to remote databases and automation or just one of these?

Comment: @P.Salmon: With both of them.

Comment: And you only have mysql at your disposal?

Comment: Thats right! Only MySQL. And this is also only needed for MySQL.